# how to use assert in if condition for web driver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have go through the process of Login username and password for Testing from excel data sheet. But, Now I Stuck in the situation of assert command in if condition that actually insert then stop and break that loop.Please help me .

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                    // Import data for Email.
                   /* cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);*/


                    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
                    String j_username = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser_UserName")).sendKeys(cell.toString());
                   /* // Import data for password.
                    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);*/

                    Cell cell1 = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
                    String j_username1 = formatter.formatCellValue(cell1);
                    System.out.println(cell1.toString());
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser_Password")).sendKeys(cell1.toString());
                    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser_LoginButton")).click();    

                }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Step1. I have taken Sheet with Name and Password Column.

Comment: Step2. Read Data from that Excel.

Comment: Step3. Login Button Click

Comment: Please post a concise version of the code that you are stuck with

Comment: Now, I've problem that there are lots of data in Excel so Loop is not going to stop for that i want to use if condition with assert that if logout button is there then Break that For loop if not then go for another cell for username and password.

Comment: Hi  Scary Wombat.  I have add the code format.

Comment: `if (someVariable) break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for element is present or not

```
IWebElement e = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Your_SignOut_Button_Id"));
```

in your case you want assert,

```
Debug.Assert(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Your_SignOut_Button_Id")), "YOUR MESSGAE TO BE DISPLAYED!");
```

you got required element (i.e NOT NULL) or not (i.e. NULL)

```
if (e == NULL) {
   break;
}
else {
   continue;
}
```